# Get Top and Left position of an FMX Control, based on screen bounds

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I'm trying to place an outside program right into an FMX `TPanel` using `SetWindowPOS` from WinAPI.
In order to do that I need the exact `Top` and `Left` values of the `TPanel` to pass it to `SetWindowPOS`. However, this value is always according to its parent, so i.e. if the `Tpanel`'s parent is a `TLayout` and no margins are set, then the value of `Top` will be 0.

I need the `Top` value according to the screen.
I tried searching for that quite a bit but I can't figure it out.
Any help with that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `ClientToScreen` + `LocalToAbsolute`?

Answer (score 2):

After just posting the question I got the simple solution

```
var
    pnt: TPointF;
begin
  pnt := myRctngl.LocalRect.TopLeft;
  pnt := myRctngl.LocalToAbsolute(pnt);
  pnt := ClientToScreen(pnt);
End;
```

`pnt` should now have the value of the Point according to the screen.

You can now use `pnt.x` and `pnt.y` to get the top/left values.